# How Do I have Multiple Sorts in a Window Function in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a SQLAlchemy query with a row_number function like this which works fine:

```
func.row_number().over(order_by=a.desc())
```

What I'd like to do is add a second sort to help with "tie breaking".  I've tried:

```
func.row_number().over(order_by=a.desc(),b.desc())
```

Which I didn't really expect to work.  I've also tried:

```
func.row_number().over(order_by=(a.desc(),b.desc()))
```

and

```
func.row_number().over(order_by=[a.desc(),b.desc()])
```

Those didn't work either.

I haven't found a syntax example online, hence my question - How do you do multiple sorts in a window function using sqlalchemy?

Comment: According to [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.over.params.order_by) the latter 2 should work as expected. Please explain further how and why they did not work.

Comment: "or list of such" - I didn't see that wording.  Thanks.  Last night I kept getting a syntax error for all three, but could not find anything wrong in the code.  This morning I see I was missing the comma separating the elements of the list in the list based solution.  (That last approach, using a list, was my preferred syntax.)  I'm not convinced the ordered pair would have worked, and I'm sure the first option shouldn't work.  Now that I have it working I'm all set - thanks!!

Comment: Passing a tuple does work, though the wording is "list". In general a sequence is a sequence in Python. Yeah, the first option is incorrect syntax to begin with: a positional argument follows a keyword argument.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

```
  func.row_number().over(order_by=and_(a.desc(), b.desc()))
```